# Snapping 2 objects together in Sketch 3

Tags: vector, sketch-app, snapping

I am trying to use Sketch 3 to create some SVG icons.  One of the big reasons I am using SVG icons is the ability to have multiple color however to do that, the SVG must be multiple shapes.  The issues I am running into is that I can seem to snap together so I always end up with something like this:

[image]

Is there anyway in Sketch 3 to be able to snap together 2 points of 2 different objects?

Comment: Can you group objects in Sketch like in Illustrator?

Comment: Yes but how does that help me snap objects together?

Comment: Also, having them in the same group does not allow for snapping

Comment: Can you combine the shape into one, flatten it, then create two new shapes again?

Comment: There is no way to split a object into 2 object in Sketch 3 that I know of

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach.
I think the best way to snap objects is snap point in Edit mode.
Let me show:

1. Here two objects I want to snap, you can see a little gap between them:

[image]

2. Select one object, triangle in my case, press Edit mode in toolbar menu. Now shape is in editing mode, select upper point and check position of it:

[image]

3. Select rect and activate Edit mode. Make rects upper left point position same as triangles upper point position:

[image]

4. Apply these actions to lower points:

[image]
[image]

5. Final result:

[image]

[Sketch file](http://ge.tt/5UyChxM2/v/0?c)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the best way. As of now, Sketch does not seem to have an option to snap to the vertices of other objects, which would make this process so much snappier (pun intended).